# Actual (current) value of UltraDMA CRC error count (SMART)?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, crc

I have some positive counts in `UltraDMA CRC error count` entry of SMART data on my HDD.

How to know if this value is actual?

It is possible related with bad cable I had previously. Does this counter counts from HDD brithday? Or from boot time?

Comment: No;  These types of errors come from a mechanical error not from a bad cable.  I have no idea what a "HDD birthday" is exactly.

Comment: @Ramhound This is from cable, educate yourself: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.

Answer (score 1):

SMART values normally do not "reset" in the normal sense of the word (get set back to zero due to some event, such as a drive power-on event). An error count can, however, decrease, *if* the condition that caused the error count to be increased no longer exists. There are a few exceptions, but UDMA CRC Error Count is not one of them.

I'm not really sure what you mean with "if this value is actual", but if you mean what I think you mean, then it follows from the above that the reported value will be the total value for the disk's life time.

So what you should be looking for is **error count *increments.*** A value holding steady means that particular aspect of the hard disk drive is stable, as far as the SMART monitoring can determine and report. (That is "stable" in the medical sense of the word; remember a patient may be for example stable but still in critical condition, which is very different from stable and healthy. SMART monitoring can work the same way. Suppose attribute 0x05 Reallocated Sectors Count is holding steady at the maximum allowed value; no further reallocations are possible, because the drive has run out of spare sectors, but that particular attribute won't indicate any further deterioration. Attribute 0xC6 Offline Uncorrectable might still indicate deterioration, however.)